# Rotating an image towards the mouse's current position

Tags: c#, xna, rotation

I am trying to make a simple game in XNA.

I have a player which has spritesheet next to it.
The spritesheet is a sort of weapon, with a tip.

How can I get this sprite to rotate with the tip facing the mouse position?

```
        float y2 = m_Mouse.Y;
        float y1 = m_WeaponOrigin.Y;
        float x2 = m_Mouse.X;
        float x1 = m_WeaponOrigin.X;

        // Get angle from mouse position.
        m_Radians = (float) Math.Atan2((y2 - y1), (x2 - x1));

Drawing with: 
activeSpriteBatch.Draw(m_WeaponImage, m_WeaponPos, r, Color.White, m_Radians, m_WeaponOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.100f);
```

while this makes it rotate, it does not follow the mouse correctly, and it behaves weirdly.

Any hints on how to make this work?

Another issue I have is to define a point and which is the muzzle, and update it based on the angle as well, so that shots will fire correctly from that point towards the mouse.

Thanks

---

Screenshots:
[image: early, getting the mouse and cursor in place]

[image: playing with the super laser]

[image: using the superlaser on every enemy type]

Thanks again, turned out to be a fun game.

Comment: Can you post an image of the weapon so we can see what type of shape you are trying to aim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, use [`Math.Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx).

```
Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
Vector2 dPos = _arrow.Position - mousePosition;

_arrow.Rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(dPos.Y, dPos.X);
```

---

**Proof of concept** (I used the plus texture for the cursor - it doesn't show on the sceenshot unfortunately):

[image: Pointing to cursor]

---

### "What is `_arrow`?"

In that example `_arrow` is of type `Sprite`, which might come in handy in some situations, and will sure make your code look a bit cleaner:

```
public class Sprite
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; private set; }

    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public float Rotation { get; set; }
    public float Scale { get; set; }

    public Vector2 Origin { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public Sprite(Texture2D texture)
    {
        this.Texture = texture;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(this.Texture, 
                         this.Position, 
                         null, 
                         this.Color, 
                         this.Rotation, 
                         this.Origin, 
                         this.Scale, 
                         SpriteEffects.None, 
                         0f);
    }
}
```

Declare:

```
Sprite _arrow;
```

Initiate:

```
Texture2D arrowTexture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("ArrowUp");
_arrow = new Sprite(arrowTexture)
        {
            Position = new Vector2(100, 100),
            Color = Color.White,
            Rotation = 0f,
            Scale = 1f,
            Origin = new Vector2(arrowTexture.Bounds.Center.X, arrowTexture.Bounds.Center.Y)
        };
```

Draw:

```
_spriteBatch.Begin();
_arrow.Draw(_spriteBatch, gameTime);
_spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: Thank you for this well explained answer!
Will post screenshots when my project has gotten a little further.